# R_MIPS_HI16/R_MIPS_LO16 pair on different register

Tags: mips, relocation

I'm trying to understand how R_MIPS_HI16 and R_MIPS_LO16 relocations work in mips.

I wrote a bit of c code:

```c
static char buf1[0x100];
static int a = 0;
static int b = 0;

char f(int i, int n)
{
    a++;
    b++;
    return buf1[n];
}
```

Compile with `mips-linux-gnu-gcc-8 -o test.o -c -O2 -G 0 -g test.c` And run objdump: `mips-linux-gnu-objdump -d -j .text test.o`

I get the following:

```
00000030 <f>:
  30:   3c070000    lui a3,0x0
  34:   3c060000    lui a2,0x0
  38:   3c020000    lui v0,0x0
  3c:   8ce50004    lw  a1,4(a3)
  40:   8cc30000    lw  v1,0(a2)
  44:   24420008    addiu   v0,v0,8
  48:   00442021    addu    a0,v0,a0
  4c:   24a50001    addiu   a1,a1,1
  50:   24630001    addiu   v1,v1,1
  54:   80820000    lb  v0,0(a0)
  58:   ace50004    sw  a1,4(a3)
  5c:   03e00008    jr  ra
  60:   acc30000    sw  v1,0(a2)
```

Now I run `mips-linux-gnu-readelf -r test.o` to get the relocation table:

```
Relocation section '.rel.text' at offset 0x79c contains 12 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
00000008  00000405 R_MIPS_HI16       00000000   .bss
00000018  00000406 R_MIPS_LO16       00000000   .bss
00000014  00000405 R_MIPS_HI16       00000000   .bss
0000001c  00000406 R_MIPS_LO16       00000000   .bss
00000030  00000405 R_MIPS_HI16       00000000   .bss
0000003c  00000406 R_MIPS_LO16       00000000   .bss
00000040  00000406 R_MIPS_LO16       00000000   .bss
00000038  00000405 R_MIPS_HI16       00000000   .bss
00000044  00000406 R_MIPS_LO16       00000000   .bss
00000058  00000406 R_MIPS_LO16       00000000   .bss
00000034  00000405 R_MIPS_HI16       00000000   .bss
00000060  00000406 R_MIPS_LO16       00000000   .bss
```

Now, according to the [ABI](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/mipsabi32.pdf), section 4-17, each R_MIPS_HI16 relocation has a matching R_MIPS_LO16. In case there is a R_MIPS_LO16 without a R_MIPS_HI16 right before it, it will refer to the previous R_MIPS_HI16.

If I understand this right, that meant that the relocations in 38 and 44 are paired. That makes sense - in address 38 we move the higher part of an address to a register (v0), and in 44 we add to the same register to complete the loading of the address.

What I don't understand is that the relocation in 58 is also coupled to the same R_MIPS_HI16, but in that address we don't access any register that was used in the previous commands, nor do they seem to be related. In fact, this command seems to be related to the pair 30 and 3c.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're observing an optimization for `a++` and `b++`.

While one might think that `b = b + 1` contains a load of `b` and and a store of `b`, requiring `lui/lw` pair for the read of `b` and `lui/sw` pair for the write of `b`, the compiler knows that both read of `b` and write of `b` require the same exact `lui`, so it eliminates the second `lui` and reuses the target register of the first `lui` — thus it is doing `lui/lw/sw`.

---

If you were writing this manually, and, had a small program. you *might* use/share a single `lui` for all the global variables.

But because these variables are allocated to `.bss` (they are all zero initialized), the linker determines the final locations of them (on some systems though they are declared together in the source program, they are individual items), and so we don't actually know how close together they will be at compile time.

Further, as this is a program fragment, we also don't know how many globals in total there will be for the program, and thus, a 64k boundary could occur between between any two globals, meaning those two globals would require different `lui`.

As the final determinations are made by the linker, the compiler assumes worst case here and uses a separate `lui` for each global variable.

---

After some discussion...

I see what you're getting at. What I've told you is that 30,3c and 58 are related to the same access of the variables, and this is true. The relocations, I am not familiar with but you may find this relevant:

https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/909

> While I understand the manner in which the ABI is explained, a HI16 does not impact the LO16 relocation fixup, Our current implementation only has the LO16 affecting the HI16 fixup due to potential carry into the upper 16-bits during HI16 computation.

The bottom line is that while the HI16 needs to be paired with a LO16 to compute the carry, a repeat of a previously paired LO16 is ok without a preceding HI16 because the appropriate carry into the HI16 has already been done — so the HI16/LO16 relocations are not truly paired 1:1.

Comment: So you claim that addresses 38, 44 and 58 contain together the `b = b + 1`? If it's so, why do they use completely different registers?

Comment: Not 38,44,58, but 30, 3c, 58 "pair" while 34, 44, and 60 also "pair"

Comment: But 38 and 58 have paired R_MIPS_HI16 and R_MIPS_LO16?

Comment: I don't know how you're determining that those are paired.  38 and 44 are pairs.

Comment: So what is the pair for 58? How can you determine it from the relocation table? I decided that 58 and 38 are paired because the R_MIPS_HI16 that comes before 58 is 38.

Comment: 30, 3c, 58 are paired, as determined by the code.  There isn't enough info in the dump of the relocations to tell what pairs

Comment: How can the loader (ld.so) know that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210110/discussion-between-elyashiv-and-erik-eidt).